# Can I set element property in xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml

For example, I have a ContextMenu for TextBox and when a user click on menu item in ContextMenu, I want to set TextBox's Text property to some value.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you seen the example in [MenuItem.Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.click.aspx)?

Comment: I don't see the connection with my question?

Comment: I wasn't sure which level of knowledge you have and if you wanted to do it without any code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Blend SDK there is a [ChangePropertyAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723951%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) available.

[This tutorial](http://asimsajjad.blogspot.com/2010/08/changepropertyaction-behavior-for.html) might help (the tutorial targets Silverlight but this is the same in WPF)

Note that you don't need Blend to use this Action; you can use it in Visual Studio too but you'll have to type the code by hand.

Answer (score 2):

If you're specifically asking if you can do this all in XAML, you can't.  Allowing your Commands and UI interactions to update the ViewModel that the rest of your View is depending on (binding to) for their values, is the correct approach.

Without seeing code: If the TextBox's Text property is already binding to a ViewModel of sorts (and I can only guess it is), then bind/set that property to be the desired result of the `MenuItem` selected in your `ContextMenu`.  Assuming your `Binding` is correct, the TextBox's value should updated accordingly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Phixed, this has nothing to do with ViewModel, its UI specific action. I have used a TextBox just as an example. More proper example would be to have a ContextMenu with Rename MenuItem, and when clicked, TreeView node should be in edit mode (to rename it). This istself doesnt have anything to do with business logic and VM. Its quite easy to do with code-behind, I was just curious if it can also be done in xaml, and it seems that ChangePropertyAction might be the solution

Comment: Ah, I assumed a ViewModel based on the fact that you're changing the value of a TextBox in your hypothetical.  You'll have to let me know how the ChangePropertyAction works out for you.

Comment: It works with MS controls, but having problem with Telerik controls, which probably cannot be resolved.

Comment: There should be nothing limiting by Telerik's controls.  They play by the same rules the rest of the WPF framework plays by, they've only extended it.  Without creating an example for you, send me some source and I will help you finish it.

Comment: Well, Telerik support told me its not supported by their controls. If you think you can do better, just try this: Have a radtreeview control and set a RadContextMenu for it. Then when a menu is clicked, set a background property of the treeview. And all this in xaml, not code behind